# How can I add the curl library to a visual studio 2017 console application?

Tags: curl, visual-c++, libcurl

I am just starting out in c++ and cannot figure out how to add libraries, in particular libcurl.  I tried a bunch of tutorials but most were for 2013/10 or didn't work.  Can anyone please explain (Preferably in standard/non technical English) how I can add the library?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of searching in internet I found a way to add libcurl in visual studio 2017.
Here is a blog written by me hope it helps.
http://develop.itarimusic.com/how-to-add-libcurl-to-Visual-Studio-2017/

Edit: Visual Studio Native Tool->cd your_directory and then run

```
 set RTLIBCFG=static
 nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=15 debug=no
 nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=15 debug=yes
```

In project setting use Of MFC -> Use MFc static library
Add the following dependencies
Normaliz.lib;Ws2_32.lib;Wldap32.lib;Crypt32.lib;advapi32.lib
Add libcurl header files and libraries to Visual Studio

Note: I have tried to summaries as much as possible. The question is too 
broad and asking for step-by-step method.